# Unexpected keyword export

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I am having this error while implementing bottom material tab navigator checked thoroughly but cant seem to find the root cause of the error

[image]

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import{StyleSheet,Text,View}from 'react-native'
import Profile from './Profile'
import Cart from './Cart'
import{createBottomTabNavigator,createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import{createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
import{Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import Home from './Home';

 class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const TabNavigator=createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home:{screen:Home,
      navigationOptions:{
        tabBarLabel:'Home',
        activeColor:'#ff0000',
        inactivecolor:'#000000',
        barStyle:{backgroundcolor:'#67ba56'},
        tabBarIcon:()=>(
          <View>
            <Icon name= {'home'}    size={25} style={{color:'#ff0000'}}      />
          </View>
        )
      }
    },
    Profile:{screen:Profile,
      navigationOptions:{
        tabBarLabel:'Profile',
        activeColor:'#ff0000',
        inactivecolor:'#000000',
        barStyle:{backgroundcolor:'#67ba56'},
        tabBarIcon:()=>(
          <View>
            <Icon name= {'profile'}    size={25} style={{color:'#ff0000'}}      />
          </View>
        )
      }
  },
  Cart:{screen:Cart,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Cart',
      activeColor:'#ff0000',
      inactivecolor:'#000000',
      barStyle:{backgroundcolor:'#67ba56'},
      tabBarIcon:()=>(
        <View>
          <Icon name= {'add-shopping-cart'}    size={25} style={{color:'#ff0000'}}      />
        </View>
      )
    }
}
  }
),
export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator)
```

I installed all the required dependencies checked the export statement but that does not seem to work
should i install my dependencies again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unwanted comma replace it with a semicolon
remove ), at the end of createMaterialBottomTabNavigator

```
and replace with 
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```